# Mapper could not assemble any primary key columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

[image]

I have created a tmp table from a sqllite table which is a subset of the original table based on various selection criteria. A sample is in the screenshot.

I'm trying to loop through the table records one at a time in order to update a field in each. I have:

```
source_table= self.source
engine = create_engine(db_path)
Base = declarative_base()
# metadata = Base.metadata
# Look up the existing tables from database
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)

# Create class that maps via ORM to the database table
table = type(source_table, (Base,), {'__tablename__': source_table})

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
i = 0
for row in session.query(table).limit(500):

    i += 1
    print object_as_dict(row)
```

But this gives:

```
ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|tmp|tmp could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'tmp'
```

How can I perform this loop ?

Comment: It'd seem your that your temporary table has no primary key(s). Have a look at ["How do I map a table that has no primary key"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key), or just use Core instead.