# Creating a primary key in sqlalchemy when creating a table instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

[image]

I have created a tmp table from a sqllite table which is a subset of the original table based on various selection criteria. A sample is in the screenshot.

I'm trying to loop through the table records one at a time in order to update a field in each. I have run into a problem detailed in [Mapper could not assemble any primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662184/mapper-could-not-assemble-any-primary-key-columns) . Based on the recommendations at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key . Based on this discussion I do have a candidate key which is a unique id : the column 'id'. Therefore, I have changed my code to:

```
source_table= self.source
engine = create_engine(db_path)
Base = declarative_base()
# metadata = Base.metadata
# Look up the existing tables from database
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)

# Create class that maps via ORM to the database table
table = type(source_table, (Base,), {'__tablename__': source_table}, __mapper_args__ = {
    'primary_key':'id'
})

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
i = 0
for row in session.query(table).limit(500):

    i += 1
    print object_as_dict(row)
```

But this gives:

```
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

How can I use the **mapper_args** argument to identify id as the primary key

edit:

I tried :

```
    table = type(source_table, (Base,), {'__tablename__': source_table}, {"__mapper_args__": {"primary_key": [Base.metadata.tables[source_table].c.id]}})
```

giving:

```
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__mapper_args__` needs to be an attribute defined on the class. Whereas you need to write

```
class Foo(Base):
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = {...}
```

when defining a class with the `class` syntax, you need to write

```
type("Foo", (Base,), {..., "__mapper_args__": {...}})
```

when defining a class with the `type` function.

Note that `__mapper_args__` may need to be

```
{"primary_key": [Base.metadata.tables[source_table].c.id]}
```

instead of

```
{"primary_key": "id"}
```

for it to work properly.

Comment: Thank you, I'm almost there but would you mind checking the edit?

Comment: @user61629 `type` takes three arguments. You're giving it four. It needs to be `type(source_table, (Base,), {"__tablename__": source_table, "__mapper_args__": ...})`.

Comment: Final answer: ->         table = type(source_table, (Base,), {"__tablename__": source_table, "__mapper_args__": {"primary_key":[Base.metadata.tables[source_table].c.id]}})